# sed to delete line(patten match) not working in my case

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to delete bellow pattern from file(/home/test), my script is not deleting it. please let me know how to delete by pattern matching.

pattern to delete:

```
'user.err        @[10.209.10.73]'
```

File:

```
root@mystique-node:~# cat /home/test
user.err        @@[10.209.10.71]
user.err        @@[10.209.10.72]
user.err        @[10.209.10.73]
root@mystique-node:~#
```

Script:

```
root@mystique-node:~# cat /home/test1.sh
aa=`cat /home/test|grep "10.209.10.73"`
sed -i "/$aa/d" /home/test
root@mystique-node:~#
```

Comment: Square brackets create a bracket expression.

Comment: Just assign the ip_addr to `sed` command is enough, `cat ...| grep ...` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** To take ip as an argument yo could use following(tested only for given samples).

```
awk -v check="10.209.10.73" '$0 !~ check' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself use `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above command too.

---

Try to escape `.` and `[`,`]` to remove their special meaning. Following `sed` may help you here.

```
sed '/\[10\.209\.10\.73\]/d' Input_file
```

Comment: @chetan h, always try to encourage users by up-voting answers(if answer is helpful to you) and give it sometime, try to select an answer(out of all answers after sometime) as correct answer too to complete the thread.

Comment: need generic solution,  becz ip will be different (cmd line argument ).

Comment: @chetanh, you could mention all your needs in single post itself, check my EDIT solution and let me know then?